# Symfony 5 - How to register a card with mangopay php sdk

Tags: php, symfony, mangopay

I'm trying to register a credit card with MangoPay.

On my service file, I've created a public function to register the card, using the package `mangopay/php-sdk-v2`.

```
// ApiUser.php

public function Registration($UserId)
    {
        $CardRegistration = new \MangoPay\CardRegistration();
        $CardRegistration->UserId = $UserId;
        $CardRegistration->Currency = "EUR";
        $CardRegistration->CardType = "CB_VISA_MASTERCARD";
        $Result = $this->mangoPayApi->CardRegistrations->Create($CardRegistration);
      $this->registration = $Result;

      return $Result;
    }
```

Its result will be an object, within three main keys: `AccessKey`, `PreRegistrationData` and `CardRegistrationURL`.

```
{ 
   [...]
   "AccessKey": "1X0m87dmM2LiwFgxPLBJ",
   "PreregistrationData": "YkgVxL1yNY4ZOfKtqEew_ZzBSGg0ie3ghohlFhb-37oidM_c0HMmR9H0WvKWb8pa2ddFLVXdicolcUIkv_kKEA",
   "CardRegistrationURL": "https://homologation-webpayment.payline.com/webpayment/getToken",
   [...]
}
```

While trying with PostMan, I just have to take the URL in the `CardRegistrationURL` and, in its `body`, add: `data` with the `PreRegistrationData`, `accessKeyRef` with `AccessKey` and `cardNumber`, `cardExpirationDate` and `cardCvx` (the `Content-Type` is `x-www-urlencoded`) 
Once clicked on the `Send` button, its response will be a long string that start by `data=`. 
With that string, I can finally update the `CardRegistration` object and give the user on MangoPay the credit card.

The problem is that while coding, I can't find a way to get the response of the `CardRegistrationURL`.

I've tried to do a `POST` while using the `http-client` package, but the response given is an object. I've checked if it was present within the object, but it was not.
I've also tried to check this: https://github.com/Mangopay/mangopay2-php-sdk/blob/master/demos/paymentDirect/payment.php and tried to emulate it, but without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Warning: You don't have to collect card details on your server side, you have to create an HTML form like this

```
<form action="CardRegistrationURL here">
   // inputs for cardNumber, expiration date ...
   // You can add an input to redirect your user after card registration, ex:
   // <input name="returnUrl" value="https://youwebsite.com">
</form>
```

You user will be redirected to MangoPay server then come back to your website. When the user comes back to your website use the request data to update card registration and do related things.

The documentation is not very clear, don't hesitate to ask MangoPay support.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but how can we recover this string? please.

Comment: Which string are you talking about?

Comment: The string that is rendered by the post of the `CardRegistrationURL`

Comment: ok you can find the "string" (the response) in the query param of the request object, try to make a `dump($request)` in your controller where your "returnUrl" is configured.